# Using an ArrayList of hashes as a TileLayout dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This seems like it should be really simple, but I'm a total newbie to Flex and am getting stuck.

Here's what I have right now, which works:

```
<s:List id="list"
        itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultComplexItemRenderer"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3"
                      requestedRowCount="2"
                      horizontalGap="0"
                      verticalGap="0" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/truck.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/suv.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/convertible.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/sedan.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/surprise.png')" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

What I'd like to do is add labels below each tile, associating each image with a string.  I want to do something like

```
<s:List id="list"
        itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultComplexItemRenderer"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3"
                      requestedRowCount="2"
                      horizontalGap="0"
                      verticalGap="0" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:BitmapImage name="Truck" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/truck.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage name="SUV" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/suv.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage name="Convertible" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/convertible.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage name="Sedan" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/sedan.png')" />
            <s:BitmapImage name="Surprise Me!" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/surprise.png')" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

but since there is no name property on the BitmapImage object, I get errors.

I guess I need to put each `BitmapImage` in an `Object` and also put in a string as a property of the object, but I can't figure out how to do this.  This is my best guess, but then I don't know how to specify the property name for the `BitmapImage`:

```
<fx:Object label="Truck">
    <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/truck.png')" />
</fx:Object>
```

After that, I guess I would make a custom ItemRenderer to read out the properties on each object?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing your metaphors a bit.  You are putting actual UI elements in your dataProvider.  In my opinion, the only thing that should be in that dataProvider is raw data.  In your case, it is a string and image data.  You use an `ItemRenderer` to apply the view element to the data.

So, just create an `Object` and forget about there being a `BitmapImage` in your `dataProvider` at all.  That object has `name` and `source` properties.

Then, create a simple `itemRenderer` that binds the `name` and the `source` properties of the `data` object which is automatically assigned for you.

A little bit like this?

```
<s:List id="list"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3"
                      requestedRowCount="2"
                      horizontalGap="0"
                      verticalGap="0" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object name="Truck" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/truck.png')" />
            <fx:Object name="SUV" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/suv.png')" />
            <fx:Object name="Convertible" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/convertible.png')" />
            <fx:Object name="Sedan" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/sedan.png')" />
            <fx:Object name="Surprise Me!" source="@Embed('../images/menus/car_types/surprise.png')" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>

    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:HGroup>
                    <s:Label text="{data.name}" />
                    <s:BitmapImage source="{data.source}" />
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Of course, pretty up that `ItemRenderer` however you see fit, but use data binding to the `data` property for whatever property you need.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I was looking for.  As for the BitmapImage, I had thought you literally had to create a UI component in order to embed the image (I don't want dynamic loading), so I guess that was part of the motivation... although I guess in retrospect that doesn't make much sense.  Thanks for clarifying everything!